# CMake Package Support - Includes and Libraries not found

Tags: c++, cmake

I am currently developing a software package, for which I'd like to provide the cmake package support (so users can find it with `find_package(...)`). The Problem is, the package is found but `FOO_INCLUDE_DIR` and `FOO_LIBRARIES` is empty.

Within my package I have several modules, each with a CMakeLists file which installs the respective library and headers with:

```
install(TARGETS ${LIBRARY_NAME} EXPORT FooTargets
    RUNTIME       DESTINATION ${Foo_RUNTIME_INSTALL_DIR}
    LIBRARY       DESTINATION ${Foo_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}
    ARCHIVE       DESTINATION ${Foo_ARCHIVE_INSTALL_DIR}
    FRAMEWORK     DESTINATION ${Foo_FRAMEWORK_INSTALL_DIR})

# Headers
install(
        DIRECTORY include/${LIBRARY_NAME}
        DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}
        FILES_MATCHING
            PATTERN "*.h"
            PATTERN "*.hpp"
)
```

The headers for the library are included with target_include_directories like this:

```
target_include_directories(${LIBRARY_NAME} PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include> # for headers when building
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${Foo_INC_INSTALL_DIR}> # for client in install mode
)
```

I checked the folders and all libraries and headers are correctly installed. In my toplevel CMakeLists I export my targets with:

```
install(
        EXPORT FooTargets
        DESTINATION ${Foo_CMAKE_CONFIG_INSTALL_DIR}
        FILE FooConfig.cmake
)
```

The config is where I assume it to be (`usr/local/lib/cmake/Foo`). So everything seems to be correct. When I look into my `FooConfig.cmake` it says:

```
# Create imported target realm_densifier_base
add_library(FooLib1 SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(FooLib1 PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/usr/local/include/Foo"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "...several libraries..."
)
```

...which is absolutely correct and exactly what I expected. What part of the puzzle is missing? Is `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` not the correct flag to be set?

Thanks for the help and best regards,

Alex

Edit:

@Guillaume Racicot already cleared most things up, I only knew the "non target" way of adding headers to my project, that was with include_directories(Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS). However, in the target-world linking against my library Foo was enough. Another thing was that I messed up some directories in the `target_include_directories(...)` command, so directories were wrong and therefore could not be found in my other project. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would `FOO_INCLUDE_DIR` or `FOO_LIBRARIES` be set? This may be how old find modules worked, but not how config files work. Even newer find modules expose targets instead of directory variables.

When generating an `XYZConfig.cmake` file, informations about *targets* will be exported, not informations on the directory.

With such exportation:

```
install(
    EXPORT FooTargets
    NAMESPACE Foo::
    DESTINATION ${Foo_CMAKE_CONFIG_INSTALL_DIR}
    FILE FooConfig.cmake
)
```

You would expect users of the package to use it like so:

```
find_package(Foo REQUIRED)

#         or PUBLIC ------v
target_link_libraries(bar PRIVATE Foo::FooLib1)
```

If your package has multiple targets in the export set, then you can link to both or only one

```
target_link_libraries(bar PRIVATE Foo::FooLib1 Foo::FooLib2)
target_link_libraries(baz PUBLIC  Foo::FooLib2) # link to lib2 only
```

When you link to an exported target like `Foo::FooLib1`, its public interface will be transitively transmitted to its user. In the example above, `bar` will inherit properties from the linked target.

So the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` of `Foo::FooLib1` and `Foo::FooLib2` will be appended to `bar`'s `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`. Same for `LINK_LIBRARIES`.

For `baz`, not only its `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` will contain `Foo::FooLib2` entries, but also its own `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` will transitively transmit the usage requirements of `Foo::FooLib2`

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't realise something changed about the CMake syntax. It's the first time I use a rather new CMake version. But I think I still didn't completely understand it. In my other package I use 'find_package(Foo REQUIRED)` just as usual, and for linking I do `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Foo::FooLib1)`. But I get the following warning in CMake: `Target "Bar" links to target "Foo::FooLib1" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?`and it does not compile due to unknown #include's.

Comment: Okay, this problem was due to some missing cmake policy. But I also messed up some of the directories in `target_include_directories`. I think I almost got it running now, the only problem I now encounter is: While building my package without installing it, everything works fine. But when I install it and want to use it from another package, the include is done with `#include <ProjectName/LibraryName/Header.h>`. This is fine for me, but inside the package it now throws error because I use `#include <LibraryName/Header.h>` is not found. In the config it exports `/usr/local/ProjectName`...

Comment: ...so `#include <LibraryName/Header.h>` should be valid in my perception. But I probably don't understand CMake not well enough yet. So I will investigate further and report back

Comment: Check what your include directories are, then check back on the actual directory structure installed.

Comment: Also, for the syntax `Foo::FooLib1` to work, you need `NAMESPACE Foo::` and not `NAMESPACE Foo`, my bad.